# Recursively traverse directory and replace function calls

Tags: python, perl, bash, sed, grep

I would like to traverse a directory recursively and find all files that have at least one of the function calls of the following set:

```
A(a)
B(a,b)
C(a,b,c)
```

now, disregarding the arguments I can get a list of such files with

```
grep -r -l '[A-C](' .
```

although I am sure I can also match the arguments somehow. On these files I want to do the following: First, I want a backup, i.e. save the original file to filename.ext_bak or something, whereas in the filename.ext I want to replace each occurence of the function call

```
X(a,...)
```

by

```
#ifdef LOL
   X_new(f(a),...)
#else
   X(a,...)
#endif
```

where X can be A,B,C and notice that each argument in X_new is wrapped in a function f(...).
Would appreciate any help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why you need totagged both python, and perl? If you working on linux platform, sed and grep should be more than enough

Comment: @ajreal, Then I wouldn't have seen it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) to traverse all files recursively (starting from the current working directory).

The `backup='_bak'` argument tells [fileinput.input](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.input) to make a backup of each file.

```
import os
import sys
import re
import fileinput

def sub_callback(match):
    func,args=match.groups()
    fargs=','.join('f({a})'.format(a=a) for a in args.split(','))
    return ('''\
#if def LOL
    {func}_new({fa})        
#else
    {func}({a})
#endif
'''.format(func=func,a=args,fa=fargs))

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for line in fileinput.input(
        (os.path.join(root,name) for name in files),
        inplace=True,
        backup='_bak'
        ):
        line=re.sub(r'\b([A-C])\((.*?)\)',sub_callback,line)
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find -type f -exec perl -i.bak -pe'
   if (my ($orig, $pre, $func, $args, $post) =
       /^((.*)\b(A|B|C)\((.*?)\)(.*?))\n/s
   ) {
       $args = join ', ', map { "f($_)" } split /,\s*/, $args;
       $_ = "#ifdef LOL\n";
       $_ .= $pre${func}_new($args)$post\n";
       $_ .= "#else\n";
       $_ .= $orig\n";
       $_ .= "#endif\n";
   }
' {} +
```

Makes a lot of assumptions. Let me know if one of them produces too many problems.

Comment: This way you can't make a backup of the files you alter, though.

Comment: @TLP, I meant to use `-i.bak`, which does make the backups. Fixed. Note that my code makes fewer assumptions than unutbu's code.

Comment: That was my thought too, but then you copy all the files, not just the ones you alter. Not sure it is possible to do with the `-i` option.

Comment: @TLP, meh. Add a grep if you care. Or clean up backups afterwards. fyi, one would need to do the same with the posted python solution, if I read it correctly. It complicates the code or requires reading the whole file into memory otherwise.